# Who wins this game of graphs?

Tags: mathematics, game, graph-theory

Albert and Bob are playing a game. This time it works like this: there are n points and Albert can ask whether or not $2$ points are connected. Bob then decides whether or not the points are connected. If, after $k$ questions, for any two points $i$ and $j$, Albert can say whether or not a path exists between them, Albert wins. If not, Bob wins. Prove if $k<n(n-1)/2$, then Bob has a winning strategy.

Comment: " Bob then decides whether or not the points are connected." So can Bob modify connections mid-game accordingly? And we can assume the answers he provides Albert will be consistent?

Comment: Yes. The answers will be consistent.

Answer (score 8):

> There can be atmost $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ distinct edges (direct connections) among $n$ points, so if $k=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ Albert knows the entire graph structure and can easily answer all path queries.

> Otherwise, Bob's strategy would be to answer "No" to every question. There will exist at least one pair of points (X,Y) such that Albert does not know whether they are directly connected.

> Bob asks Albert whether there is a path between X and Y. A graph with no connections and a graph where there is only a single connection that goes from X to Y will both be consistent to all the previous answers, so Albert cannot know for sure.